# PowerShell process execution in Java skips order

Tags: java, powershell, javafx

So I am trying to write a java application that executes a PowerShell command and reports back on the progress. 
The current window is part of a bigger application that I am working on.

The issue I am having is that a bunch of code is just not doing anything just because there is a PowerShell command being run later down the line, and instead the whole application waits for the PS command to finish running before doing anything else and just freezes until thats done.

Short version is that a line of code that comes after a bunch of other code is somehow stopping stuff before it from execution.

```
public class dog extends FrontEnd {

static Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
static double sw = screenSize.getWidth();
static double sh = screenSize.getHeight();
public static String targetFile;

public static void main(String[] args){ }

public static void newWindow() throws IOException {       
    VBox vb = new VBox();
    vb.setPadding(new Insets(10, 20, 20, 20));
    vb.setSpacing(10);

    int x = 400;int y = 400;
    Scene secondScene = new Scene(vb, x, y);

    Stage secondStage = new Stage();
    secondStage.setTitle("Second Stage");
    secondStage.setScene(secondScene);         

    //Set position of second window
    secondStage.setX( (sw/2) - (x) );
    secondStage.setY( (sh/2) - (y) );
    secondStage.show();

    Label secondLabel = new Label("Output: ");

    TextArea areaOfText = new TextArea();
    areaOfText.setText("0 \n");
    areaOfText.setPrefHeight(60);
    areaOfText.setPrefWidth(60);    

    areaOfText.setEditable(false);

    vb.getChildren().add(secondLabel);
    vb.getChildren().add(areaOfText);

    runCommand(vb, areaOfText);
}


public static void runCommand(VBox vb, TextArea areaOfText) throws IOException {

// // this is the part of the code that is causing the problem
    String command = "powershell.exe for($i = 0; $i -lt 200; $i++ ) {echo $i}";
    Process powerShellProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    powerShellProcess.getOutputStream().close();
    String line;

    //output reading
    BufferedReader output = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getInputStream()));
    if (output.readLine() != null) {
        System.out.println("Output:");
        while ((line = output.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            areaOfText.setText(areaOfText.getText() + line + "\n");
        }       
    }
    output.close();  

    //error reading
    BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(powerShellProcess.getErrorStream()));
    if (err.readLine() != null) {
        System.out.println("Error:");
        while ((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            areaOfText.setText(areaOfText.getText() + line + "\n"); 
        }
    }
    err.close();                
    Label done = new Label("done");
    vb.getChildren().add(done);
}}
```

[image: this is what it looks like before reaching the PS process line]

[image: This is what it looks like at the end of the run]

Comment: Not a Java expert, so just asking: Is the powershell process being run in the same runspace on its own thread?

Comment: I would debug this program and get a stack trace when it appears to be hanging. At some point your program is blocking, probably when trying to read the output buffer from the PowerShell process. I suspect that block is preventing your application from performing draw updates. I'm not sure, but you may need to spin the PowerShell monitor into its own thread.